# How to send post information with in a window.location.replace code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My website works like this:
1. User enters username and pass and press submit.
2. On submit, an ajax is sent to a page that checks the information and echos back  1, 2, or 3.
3. Based on ajax result, it sends the user to the application window.

WHAT I NEED: When the user is sent to the application window, I want the user id to be pasted in post to the new address.

```
    <script>
$(document).on("click", "#submit", function(event)
{
    var user = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var pwd = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
    $.post("userExistCheck.php",
    {
        userName: user,
        userPass: pwd
    },
    function(result)
    {
      if (result == "0")
      {
        window.location.replace("Moment/momentApp.php");
      }
      else if (result == "1")
      {
        alert("Password is incorrect!");
      }
      else
      {
        alert("User does not exist!");
      }
    });
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi just change this line

```
window.location.replace("Moment/momentApp.php?userid=" + userid);
```

Answer (score 1):

***Try something like this***

I hope this is you want or else go with mamta answer :)

**Html**

```
<input type="hidden" id="userid" name="userid" value="1" />
```

**Jquery**

```
var userid = document.getElementById("userid").value;

$.post("userExistCheck.php",
    {
        userName: user,
        userPass: pwd,
        userid : userid //here u can pass the userid 
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="userid" id="userid" />
<script>
 $(document).on("click", "#submit", function(event)
   {
      var userid = document.getElementById("userid").value;
    }
</script>
```

So, basically with this you can send the user id also. I have not written the whole code but the necessary part which should be appended